# Postgres Shared Memory Issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-replication

I'm unable to restart my postgres server. I believe it is related to it's attempted usage of shared memory.

Host is Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS

Postgres is 9.5

```
root@host:/# ls -lah /run/shm/
total 0
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root  40 Oct 21 17:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 800 Oct 21 17:32 ..
```

Error is:

```
2016-10-21 17:42:21 UTC [2624-1] FATAL:  could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1804289383": Read-only file system
```

Comment: Are you running this in a docker container? Seems like a lot of people are having problems like this with docker if the database was created outside of docker.

Comment: I am not. I believe the issue is related to us patching cve-2016-5195 which looks look to have broken in some way /run/shm. I'm still investigating. If this turns out to be the answer I'll answer my own question.